# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 and I am receiving the following error:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
At line:30 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:00
Invoke-ManageServiceTask : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:47
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-ManageServiceTask], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Invoke-ManageServiceTask
```

I had another few errors prior which I resolved. This one I am scratching my head at. I traced it back to the Install-SitecoreConfiguration file where the `$entry` is however I cannot understand what I am looking for as this is fully new to me. I deleted the certificates etc previously as that was causing another error.

Any additional questions are welcomed that I am provide more information to, right now I am unsure what more could be useful. I have attached picture as well.

[image]

Comment: This question is probably better fit for the [SiteCore Support portal](https://support.sitecore.net/)

Comment: Thanks! Ill try that.

Comment: The error is related to `@solrParams` check to make sure it has all the parameters needed (e.g. Name) to execute.

Comment: @HAL9256 the solrParams don't have a name field with the Sitecore documentation, and the $entry field in the Install-SitecoreConfiguration file came as standard and isn't required to be changed. I am however missing a license.xml file also so may have issues there too.